# Database android select from table

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have an database that I've putted in my assets folder that and I'm using this `DataBaseHelper` class.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.onlywithalcohol/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "Alcohol_DB";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }


    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public boolean isOpen()
    {
        Log.v("test",myDataBase.getPath());
        return myDataBase.isOpen();
    }

    public Cursor selectRecord(int id){
        Cursor c =myDataBase.rawQuery("Select title from alcorecords where id="+id, null);
          Log.v("test", c.toString());
        return c;
    }


        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
       // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
       // to you to create adapters for your views.
```

Can anybody tell me how to to make a simple select function. I've made this function

```
 public Cursor selectRecord(int id){
        Cursor c =myDataBase.rawQuery("Select title from alcorecords where id="+id, null);
          Log.v("test", c.toString());
        return c;
    }
```

but it gives me error telling me there is no such table in the database. What can I do to make this baby work :)

Comment: after you run this code is `Alcohol_DB.db` in `/data/data/com.example.onlywithalcohol/databases/`? if so, can you run `sqlite3` and query `sqlite_master` for the tables in it?

Comment: How did you create your database?

Comment: @PatrykDobrowolski imported from csv file in sqlite browser

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem last week. I think that you need to append the file name extension to `DB_NAME`, so it becomes `"Alcohol_DB.sqlite"` or `".db"`. The reason why you get the meassage **"no such table in the database"** is that an empty database is created even tough it does not copy your database from you resources.

**Tips:**

If you make any alerations to your database you should delete the application data on the emulator so it will copy the new database. To do that go to `Settings->Applications->Manage applications->YOUR_APP->Clear data`.

If you use Eclipse, you can check if the file has been copied by downloading the database file from the emulator. To do this you need to open the DDMS perspective in Eclipse `Window->Open perspective->Other...->DDMS`. Choose your emulator on the left and go to the "File Explorer" tab. You will find your database in `data/data/your.package.name/database/`. Select the file and press the "Pull file"-button in the top right corner of the tab. You can now inspect the file with your preferred SQLite manager.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

I also changed `checkDataBase()` in my code to:

```
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    File dbFile = new File(myPath); 
    return dbFile.exists(); 
}
```

Comment: @BozidarPrcovski Did you try to pull the file? If so, what did the database contain?

Comment: @BozidarPrcovski If the table "alcorecords" exists in the file pulled from the emulator/device, than I'm not sure what causes the problem. Does the table "android_metadata" exist?

Comment: no only the alcorecords table. Should be another table named android_metadata?

Comment: I'm not sure if you need it, but i have created the table in my database. Create it by using this query `CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT)`. And insert 'en_US' into the table. You could also take a look at the `SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS`-flag for `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()`. Remember to delete the data on the device/emulator if you edit the database.